# Unable to add signing key for R 4.0 (cran40's repo) on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: r, ubuntu, apt

Following the instructions in [How To Install R on Ubuntu 20.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-r-on-ubuntu-20-04), I ran

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
```

However, I got

```
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.1GsKgnB078/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out
```

I have also followed the installation guide given by the [R Linux offical websites](https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/), trying the command

```
wget -qO- https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu/marutter_pubkey.asc
```

But I waited for a long time and still got no response. As I only have very preliminary knowledge of Linux, I currently have no clue about how to find out the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What matters is the key *id* not the server as the servers are mirrored so if it times out, try another.  For what it is worth for me (under Docker for ease of setup / cleanup)

```
(root):/# apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.mSkX9qZonO/gpg.1.sh --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E298A3A825C0D65DFD57CBB651716619E084DAB9
gpg: key 51716619E084DAB9: "Michael Rutter <marutter@gmail.com>" 1 new signature
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:         new signatures: 1
(root):/#
```

So maybe try again?  I also offer it  [in this script](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/r2u/blob/master/inst/scripts/add_cranapt_focal.sh#L20C19-L20C19) to set up [r2u](https://eddelbuettel.github.io/r2u) which uses these binaries along with over 20,000 CRAN packages as binaries you can install.  So the step runs pretty often.

So in conclusion, it may be a temporary  network issue for you, or maybe something more sinister that a port is blocked.  The service itself is fine.